# How to pass parameters to custom event listener and prevent default in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, parameter-passing, preventdefault

I have to pass some argument to event handler and need to prevent default events. How to achieve this? By reactjs onMouseUp we can pass parameter but now because of passive events can't prevent default (eg: event.preventDefault();) But in case of custom event listener we can prevent default but not able to pass argument. Any solution will appreciable. Here is my code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.svgNode.current.addEventListener("mouseUp", this.mouseUpHandler, {
      passive: false,
    });
  }
mouseUpHandler(someParam, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

render() {
  let someParam = "somevalue";
  return () {
    <svg ref={this.svgNode} onMouseUp={this.mouseUpHandler.bind(this, someParam)} >
    /*some child nodes */
    </svg>
  }
}
```

Note: event.preventDefault() inside default event listener will cause error because target will treat as passive

Comment: How does `someParam` vary, or do multiple elements receive the listener? Can you post a bit more of the actual code, rather than placeholder code? I can think of a few solutions, but which is most elegant depends on how the parameter can change.

Comment: No. only one element svg. one function returns someParam so we need to use this in svg event handlers and I need to handle mouse press, mouse move, mouse wheel events in same svg, no iterations to svg. need to prevent default behaviours such as whole page scroll, drag selections etc.. that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addEventHandler` and pass already bound event handler with your custom parameter, for example:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  svgNode;
  someParam = "somevalue";

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.svgNode = React.createRef();
    // if you need to access dynamic value use this
    this.mouseUpHandler = this.mouseUpHandler.bind(this, () => this.someParam);

    // uncomment if you need to access static value, which will not be modified, you can pass it directly
    // this.mouseUpHandler = this.mouseUpHandler.bind(this, this.someParam);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.svgNode.current.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUpHandler, {
      passive: false
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.svgNode.current.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUpHandler);
  }

  mouseUpHandler(someParam, event) {
    console.log(someParam, event);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg ref={this.svgNode}>
        <circle
          cx="50"
          cy="50"
          r="40"
          stroke="green"
          strokeWidth="4"
          fill="yellow"
        />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}
```

take a look at [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-meadow-tt2fn).

Comment: this is an good example but dont forget to removehandler on `compoenentWillUnmount` lifectyle

Comment: Great, but I need to change someParam inside render and need to pass updated someParam to the handler

Comment: @ShibinRajuMathew things can get bit messy in that case, technically you could pass a function which will return you somevalue, and than you can just call the function to get a new value. `this.mouseUpHandler = this.mouseUpHandler.bind(this, () => this.someParam);` and you can update your variable in render function.

Comment: @DipenShah Yeah that's right update the answer with that function call.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to handle react event listener.

for your case, I would use `SyntheticEvent` in ReatJS.

```
...

const mouseUpHandler = (event, parameter) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(parameter);
}

render() {
  let someParam = "somevalue";
  return () {
    <svg onMouseEnter={(e) => mouseUpHandler(e, 'print this')} >
    /*some child nodes */
    </svg>
  }
}

...
```

note that the onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events propagate from the element being left to the one being entered instead of ordinary bubbling and do not have a capture phase and The specific mapping is not part of the public API and may change at any time.

So reading following article would help your further problem

- https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events
- https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: We can't prevent default like old fashion. That's what i mentioned in note..

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass an arrow function to the `svg` component like:

```jsx
<svg 
  ref={this.svgNode} 
  onMouseUp={(event) => this.mouseUpHandler(event, someParam)}
>
  /*some child nodes */
</svg>
```

Then your event handler would look something like this:

```js
mouseUpHandler(event, someParam) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```